# Pygooglevoice login error

Tags: python, sms

Someone else asked this question but had no replies so I am asking it again.
I'm trying to use pygooglevoice API but when I run the SMS.py example script it gives me a login error.
I have Enthought python installed and I'm thinking that maybe I need to install other stuff as well in order for this to run. I looked at the [instructions](http://sphinxdoc.github.com/pygooglevoice/install.html) and when I tried installing python-setuptools manually because don't have yum installed I got an error. Is that the reason why sms.py isn't working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Rigs! The standard question format is to provide a short piece of code that demonstrates your particular problem, expected input and output and any relevant error messages verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

Following works for me. I followed steps given at [pygooglevoice project discussion board, comment # 17](http://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/issues/detail?id=60#c17). Below are steps if one is starting from the scratch.

```
#Command line Google Voice:
#Updated Jan 10, 2013

#required tools:
sudo apt-get install python python-simplejson python-setuptools
sudo easy_install simplejson

# if gvoice was installed previously, then uninstall it:
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googlevoice
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygooglevoice*

#download pygooglevoice:
wget http://pygooglevoice.googlecode.com/files/pygooglevoice-0.5.tar.gz
tar -xf pygooglevoice-0.5.tar.gz
cd pygooglevoice

# edit settings.py to match correct Google Voice URL on line # 22:
nano googlevoice/settings.py

#correct URL:
LOGIN = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=grandcentral'
#you may check if URL is linking to Google Voice login page in browser.
#save and quit settings.py

#install gvoice:
sudo python setup.py install

#Login and make call for the first time:
gvoice # enter login email/pwd
  gvoice> call #follow prompts and make a call
  gvoice>send_sms # or s to send sms
  gvoice>exit #quit gvoice

#After first login, you may like to edit .gvoice for default actions:
sudo nano ~/.gvoice

#end
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem before. My version is 0.5 (installed by pip) and my system is OSX 10.8.
After reading issue 60 #17, I have just changed the line 
**LOGIN = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=grandcentral'**
to
**LOGIN = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=grandcentral'**
in the file **settings.py** and then problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I made a clone which currently works (at least for sending SMS messages):  http://code.google.com/r/kkleidal-pygooglevoiceupdate/

The problem was that Google changed the login URL.  In addition, I added a few params to the POST request which may have helped solve some issues it was running into with the POST request.  Log in should work smoothly now.

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get install python python-simplejson python-setuptools
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/pygooglevoice/pygooglevoice-0.5.tar.gz
tar -zxvf pygooglevoice-0.5.tar.gz
cd pygooglevoice-0.5
sudo apt-get install python python-setuptools
cd ~/
touch bin/smsme
chmod +x bin/smsme
vim bin/smsme

Comment: When answering a question with a piece of code or a command to execute, you should provide some context explaining what the code/command does and why it's a solution to the OP's problem.